# Delete empty lines in csv file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, vi

I have a file with 4 million of lines, every line ends with the char $, but I mistakenly add a new line  after the the line delimiter while scraping a website, so right now it is looking like this:

```
fist name, last name, phone, address, postal code, city, region,$

$

fist name, last name, phone, address, postal code, city, region,$

$
```

the new line '$' only shows up of course if I use :set list, but I'm trying to use this file for a bulk insert in mysql and I'm having problems with it now.

I would like to change the file to:

```
fist name, last name, phone, address, postal code, city, region,$

fist name, last name, phone, address, postal code, city, region,$
```

How can I do this? with sed or awk or even vi ? looked up around and what I found is not really applying to this case.

please don't take in consideration the extra empty line shown above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove blank lines with `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' yourfile.csv
```

To remove lines consisting of a single `$`:

```
sed -i '/^$$/d' yourfile.csv
```

Most versions of sed support the `-i` switch; if yours does not you will need e.g. `sed '/^$$/d' yourfile.csv > newfile.csv`.

Removing blank lines with white space is more complicated. This usually works:

```
sed '/^ *$/d' yourfile.csv
```

If this is not sufficient, try checking also for tabs. For older sed's, this will work:

```
sed '/^[ X]*$/d' yourfile.csv
```

where `X` here a tab, entered via <kbd>Control-V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Newer sed's will take a `[ \t\r]*` or `\s*` or `[[:space:]]*`, sometimes requiring a `-E` switch.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` can filter lines by match (or negative match) against a regex. To exclude empty lines:

```
grep -v '^$' yourfile.csv > yourfile_fixed.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I believe this should work! But I actually just found that only the first 100 lines are like this because I had to do some copy and paste with these first 100 entries.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

#### With `awk`:

```
awk 'NF' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

#### With `sed` (in-place changes so make sure to backup your file using `-i.bak`):

```
sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

#### With `vi`:

```
:g/^$/d
```

Comment: Just loved `awk 'NF' ` approach!